# Someone has any idea why this code does not work for firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This [code](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4HPmM) works for chrome as I want but it does not work for firefox.

```
ul {
    list-style:none; 
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}

a {
    display:block;
    margin:10px;
}

a:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
    color:red; 
}
```

and

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that on firefox instead of moving text 2 px up, it moves borders two px down. How can I fix this?

If there is no idea, then, please, suggest another version which will have the same effect on text inside .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
a { display:block; ... }
```

to

```
a { display:inline-block; ... }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. But could you explain what was the problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way: http://jsfiddle.net/dXSS9/

Here you can find reasons:

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: I could not find the explanation why I need float:left in order to get desired result. Could you please copy the text here?

Comment: Also here is another answer with changing a { display:block; ... } to a { display:inline-block; ... }. Which is the way to go?

Comment: But he can not explain his solution. Can you do that, please?

Comment: Not sure about the reason, can you try with doctype 'strict'?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=599882